# Error "! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } l.34 \end{align*}"

Tags: errors, align, exam, missing

I don't understand what went wrong:

```
\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Evaluate the limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{8\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$$
\begin{solution}
\begin{align*}
$$=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{8\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$$ \\
$$=&\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{8\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\times\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$$ \\
$$=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\sin^2(x)(1+\cos(x))}{1-\cos^2(x)}$$ \\
$$=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\sin^2(x)(1+\cos(x))}{\sin^2(x)}$$ \\
$$=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}4(1+\cos(x))$$ \\
$$=&4(1+\cos(0))$$ \\
$$=&4(1+1)=8$$ \\
\end{align*}
\end{solution}
```

And it prints out aligned but with weird text all the way on the right side.

Thank you so much

Comment: `$$...$$` is deprecated anyway, but definitely wrong inside of `align*` -- just omit it, you're using 'display math' already with `align*`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are the `$$` in the align section. Also, your code is not complete/compilable. But, I think you want something like this.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\printanswers
\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Evaluate the limit:
\[ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{8\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)} \]
\begin{solution}
\begin{align*}
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{8\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)} \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{8\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\times\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)} \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\sin^2(x)(1+\cos(x))}{1-\cos^2(x)} \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\sin^2(x)(1+\cos(x))}{\sin^2(x)} \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}4(1+\cos(x)) \\
&=4(1+\cos(0)) \\
&=4(1+1)=8 \\
\end{align*}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `$$...$$` by `\[...\]` and I might upvote `:-)`

Comment: Thank you very much. It was only part of my document but it is fixed now. Thank you.